# Can I change elements while iterating them with Iterable.forEach(Consumer)?

Tags: java, foreach, iterable

Can I change elements while iterating them with Iterable.forEach(Consumer)? Or within Consumer.accept(E) I can only read elements of underlying Iterable, but not change them?

If I can change them, what is the correct syntax?

```
ArrayDeque d = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
d.add(1);
d.add(2);
d.add(3);
d.add(4);

Consumer<Integer> cons = (e)->{e = e*10;}; // compiles!

d.forEach(cons);

System.out.println(d); // 1 2 3 4 not 10 20 30 40
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is the same as:

```
for (Integer e : d) {
   e = e * 10;
}
```

But assigning to e does not change its value in the deque.

To do what you want, do this.

```
 d = d.stream().map(a -> a * 10).collect(
            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
 System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` takes a Consumer parameter that returns nothing, and per your example, each `e` is a copy of an element in the `ArrayDeque`, so you cannot replace elements using a `forEach`.

If you want to do `e*10` on each element for one task (like printing them), you can convert the `ArrayDeque` to a `Stream`, and use map():

```
d.stream().map(e -> e*10).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Doing this will show that each element in the Deque was multiplied by 10.

If you want to actually replace the elements in the `ArrayDeque`,

```
d = d.stream().map(e -> e*10).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
```

Comment: AFAI could see OP wants to mutate original list not just sout modified elements, which semantics of `forEach` do not allow.

Comment: @kalimba good call. Just added the workaround to your point to my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't modify elements while using `forEach` as its `action` is `Consumer` which only `accepts` the value.
Example snippet for `forEach` method

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
 for (T t : this)
     action.accept(t);
```

Main thing to focus is it does not generate any value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  According to the [documentation for `ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: If the deque is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will generally throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).